# Display content-type fields in two column table format?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content-type with 5 field. how can I display these field in two column table format in Drupal 7?  Create node--content-type.tpl.php and theme it or is there any simpler way to do it?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [field_group_table](https://drupal.org/project/field_group_table) module. Once you enable it, you can visit the **'view mode'** you want to change and create a **'field group'**. Add all the fields you want show as table into this 'field group'. Now set the group to us field_group_table. This must get your job done.

Comment: installed field_group_table module and enabled. can see create field group in my content type, but how to add all my field to this group?

Comment: go to 'manage display' (and not manage fields).  Over here create a field group and select the table display formatter. Add ( drag ) fields that need to be displayed in the table into this group.

Comment: Many Thanks.first time i didn't pay attention that you can drag field under your field group.  solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new view mode for node or tpl.php file(as you wrote) or write some preprocess function.
Also you can create view which will show all node field and put it to the page(not good solution).

But what you really need it is Panels module - you can create every layout you want with panels.